# how to insert into circular list (stuck in loop)

Tags: c++, loops, circular-list

I have this insert function that is suppose to insert into a linked list in ascending order. I think I have the function right. The problem is that I am stuck in a loop and I don't know why because everything compiles.

```
void list::insertElement(int element)
{
    //ascending order
    node *temp, *curr;
    temp = new node;
    temp->item = element;
    numberofelements++; 
    if(head ==NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        head->next = head;
    }
    else {
        curr = head;
        do 
        {
            if (((curr->item <= element)&& (curr->next->item >=element)) ||curr->next==head)
            {
                temp->next = curr->next;
                curr->next = temp;
                if (element < head -> item)
                {
                    head = temp;
                }
            }
                curr = curr->next;

        }while(curr!= head);
    }
}//end of function
```

Comment: If it compiles, run it line by line and see what happens.

Comment: You can do that using a debugger. Google for more information.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr : add a retrun just after you have inserted

the problem is, when you insert, you don't stop the loop, as the loop stops only when `current==head`

when you insert, current isn't modified, so it's on the element before the one inserted, so then the `curr = curr->next;` put it on the inserted element, so next element is `head` and the element and the inserting condition is met again of course, so it's inserted again, and when it's inserted again, executing

```
temp->next = curr->next;
curr->next = temp;
```

make them looping, because `temp->next = current->next = temp`

PS : even if it is here obvious, when you use a struct or class you should really give us how it is defined exactly (functionnal code always make more people able to help you fast)